# django admin overriding change_view with foreignkey filter

Tags: django, django-admin

Here in my django ModelAdmin I want to **filter foreignkey choices** based on current user's group and I want to achieve it both in add and change form. I have achieved it in add view by using following code.

**add_view**

```
def add_view(self, request, form_url = '', extra_context = None):
    service_sector = common.getServiceSector(request.user)
    ModelForm = self.get_form(request)
    if request.POST:
        form = ModelForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    else:
        form = ModelForm()
    if service_sector:
        qs = form['member'].field.queryset
        qs = qs.filter(service_sector = service_sector)
        form['member'].field.queryset = qs
    adminForm = helpers.AdminForm(form, list(self.get_fieldsets(request)),
    self.prepopulated_fields, self.get_readonly_fields(request),
    model_admin=self)
    context = {
    'adminform': adminForm,
    'is_popup': "_popup" in request.REQUEST,
    'show_delete': False,
    'root_path': self.admin_site.root_path,
    }
    context.update(extra_context or {})
    return self.render_change_form(request, context, form_url=form_url, add=True)
```

Here it is working fine. In this model I have a unique field **Email** and that is causing the problem in change_view. I have given my change_view code below.

**change_view**

```
def change_view(self, request, object_id, form_url = '', extra_context = None):
    qs = self.model._default_manager.get_query_set()

    service_sector = common.getServiceSector(request.user)
    bene_object = Beneficiary.objects.get(pk=object_id)
    ModelForm = self.get_form(request, bene_object)
    if request.POST:
        form = ModelForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    else:                     

        form = ModelForm(instance=bene_object)            
    if service_sector:
        qs = form['member'].field.queryset
        qs = qs.filter(service_sector = service_sector)
        form['member'].field.queryset = qs
    adminForm = helpers.AdminForm(form, list(self.get_fieldsets(request)),
    self.prepopulated_fields, self.get_readonly_fields(request),
    model_admin=self)
    context = {
    'adminform': adminForm,
    'is_popup': "_popup" in request.REQUEST,
    'show_delete': False,
    'root_path': self.admin_site.root_path,
    }
    context.update(extra_context or {})
    return self.render_change_form(request, context, form_url = form_url, change = True)
```

Even though I have given `change = True` in my change_view return, it is trying to save the object as new one. So I'm getting an error `Email already exists` as the email field is unique value field. Or is it possible to use the normal change_view return as follows:

```
return super(ModelAdmin, self).change_view(request, form_url, extra_context)
```

If so, how can I filter foreignkey choices. Or how to use `render_change_form` to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have resolved this issue and posting the answer here which may help others. The question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10556288/1095090/) helped me to fix this issue. With the following code I have done foreignkey filter based on user's group, for both add and change form in django admin with inline formsets in it. I'm giving the code below:

```
def render_change_form(self, request, context, *args, **kwargs):
    model = self.model
    opts = model._meta
    formsets = []

    #Change view
    if 'change' in kwargs.keys():
        object_id   = kwargs['obj'].id  #To get object id
        object      = Modelobjects.get(pk=object_id)
        ModelForm   = self.get_form(request, object)
        qs          = self.model._default_manager.get_query_set()
        if request.POST:
            form = ModelForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        else:
            form = ModelForm(instance = object)
        service_sector = common.getServiceSector(request.user)
        if service_sector:
            #To filter foreignkey
            qs = form['member'].field.queryset
            qs = qs.filter(service_sector = service_sector)
            form['member'].field.queryset = qs
        adminForm = helpers.AdminForm(form, list(self.get_fieldsets(request)),
        self.prepopulated_fields, self.get_readonly_fields(request),
        model_admin=self)
        media = self.media + adminForm.media

        #To get inline formsets used
        prefixes = {}
        for FormSet, inline in zip(self.get_formsets(request),
                                   self.inline_instances):
            prefix = FormSet.get_default_prefix()
            prefixes[prefix] = prefixes.get(prefix, 0) + 1
            if prefixes[prefix] != 1:
                prefix = "%s-%s" % (prefix, prefixes[prefix])
            formset = FormSet(instance=object, prefix=prefix,
                              queryset=inline.queryset(request))
            formsets.append(formset)

        inline_admin_formsets = []
        for inline, formset in zip(self.inline_instances, formsets):
            fieldsets = list(inline.get_fieldsets(request))
            readonly = list(inline.get_readonly_fields(request))
            inline_admin_formset = helpers.InlineAdminFormSet(inline, formset,
                fieldsets, readonly, model_admin=self)
            inline_admin_formsets.append(inline_admin_formset)
            media = media + inline_admin_formset.media

    else:
        #Add view
        ModelForm   = self.get_form(request)
        qs          = self.model._default_manager.get_query_set()
        if request.POST:
            form = ModelForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        else:
            form = ModelForm()
        service_sector = common.getServiceSector(request.user)
        if service_sector:
            qs = form['member'].field.queryset
            qs = qs.filter(service_sector = service_sector)
            form['member'].field.queryset = qs
        adminForm = helpers.AdminForm(form, list(self.get_fieldsets(request)),
        self.prepopulated_fields, self.get_readonly_fields(request),
        model_admin=self)
        media = self.media + adminForm.media

        prefixes = {}
        for FormSet, inline in zip(self.get_formsets(request),
                                   self.inline_instances):
            prefix = FormSet.get_default_prefix()
            prefixes[prefix] = prefixes.get(prefix, 0) + 1
            if prefixes[prefix] != 1:
                prefix = "%s-%s" % (prefix, prefixes[prefix])
            formset = FormSet(instance=self.model(), prefix=prefix,
                              queryset=inline.queryset(request))
            formsets.append(formset)

        inline_admin_formsets = []
        for inline, formset in zip(self.inline_instances, formsets):
            fieldsets = list(inline.get_fieldsets(request))
            readonly = list(inline.get_readonly_fields(request))
            inline_admin_formset = helpers.InlineAdminFormSet(inline, formset,
                fieldsets, readonly, model_admin=self)
            inline_admin_formsets.append(inline_admin_formset)
            media = media + inline_admin_formset.media

    context = {
    'adminform': adminForm,
    'title': _('Add %s') % force_unicode(opts.verbose_name),
    'is_popup': "_popup" in request.REQUEST,
    'show_delete': False,
    'media': mark_safe(media),
    'inline_admin_formsets': inline_admin_formsets,
    'root_path': self.admin_site.root_path,
    }
    return super(ModelAdmin, self).render_change_form(request, context, args, kwargs)
```

Here the object id is obtained from `kwargs['obj'].id` and foreignkey is filtered by

```
qs = form['member'].field.queryset
qs = qs.filter(service_sector = service_sector)
form['member'].field.queryset = qs
```

Here `common.getServiceSector` is a custom method I'm using for my foreignkey filter conditions. You can define your own method for your requirements. Hope this will be helpful to others. Thanks.